# Issues pushing react project to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I don't understand how to interpret my heroku error log, when I try to open my created heroku site it shows:

`Cannot GET /`

I tried installing the latest version of NPM, but my site still isn't displaying.

Being that im following a tutorial, it might be a version issue, i see NPM ERR pop up on an older version of npm, not sure why its doing that when I have the latest npm installed now (5.0.4) when I do a version check.

The site appears to work fine on a local 3000 server.

My heroku logs are as follows:

```
2017-06-28T23:04:52.372037+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-06-28T23:04:52.372037+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-06-28T23:04:52.372038+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-06-28T23:04:52.372039+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-06-28T23:04:52.372039+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
2017-06-28T23:04:52.383493+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-28T23:04:52.396422+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-06-28T23:04:52.396709+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-06-28T23:04:52.396923+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.11.0
2017-06-28T23:04:52.397112+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-06-28T23:04:52.397309+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-06-28T23:04:52.397494+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! boilerplate@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2017-06-28T23:04:52.398044+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-06-28T23:04:52.397653+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-06-28T23:04:52.398174+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the boilerplate@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2017-06-28T23:04:52.398346+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-06-28T23:04:52.398523+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the boilerplate package,
2017-06-28T23:04:52.398696+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-06-28T23:04:52.398870+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-06-28T23:04:52.399030+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-28T23:04:52.399185+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-06-28T23:04:52.399505+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-06-28T23:04:52.400524+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls boilerplate
2017-06-28T23:04:52.400683+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-28T23:04:52.399354+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs boilerplate
2017-06-28T23:04:52.406230+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-28T23:04:52.406243+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-06-28T23:04:52.406244+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-06-28T23:04:52.490353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-06-28T23:04:52.503504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-28T23:07:00.596226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=76fc743d-19fc-424b-940d-988d097c270d fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-28T23:07:01.177501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=e35ffa25-0dc5-4640-bb69-5efca62cba8c fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-28T23:10:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2017-06-28T23:10:43.396212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-06-28T23:10:43.099640+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 345df8dd by user 
2017-06-28T23:10:43.099640+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user 
2017-06-28T23:10:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-06-28T23:10:45.999251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-06-28T23:10:49.484015+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-28T23:10:49.484037+00:00 app[web.1]: > boilerplate@1.0.0 start /app
2017-06-28T23:10:49.484038+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-06-28T23:10:49.484039+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-28T23:10:49.792901+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server is up on port 24384
2017-06-28T23:10:50.221470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-06-28T23:10:53.671545+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=a5de80e1-f0b5-4329-9f74-ae5e98398e60 fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=32ms status=302 bytes=367 protocol=https
2017-06-28T23:10:53.740316+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=84f43557-f90f-4d07-bb39-673ccf09c286 fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
2017-06-28T23:10:54.137448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=1956cf5d-f403-47c0-a91c-3633003664ed fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=394 protocol=http
2017-06-28T23:10:55.220395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=bb7d6dd3-bfad-4a4f-a63d-12bac9276980 fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
2017-06-28T23:11:15.965019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=24dc679c-3902-4702-8645-aa844f9a8b54 fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
2017-06-28T23:11:29.290601+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=f484100c-a489-44cc-b1d4-02d3e36b95e0 fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
2017-06-28T23:11:29.268216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=24ce79d7-8772-4c8a-9c36-fa204ac21497 fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=367 protocol=https
2017-06-28T23:27:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2017-06-28T23:27:22.606722+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user 
2017-06-28T23:27:22.606722+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b1e441d1 by user 
2017-06-28T23:27:23.046995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-06-28T23:27:23.047929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-06-28T23:27:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-06-28T23:27:23.502295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-06-28T23:27:23.616535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-06-28T23:27:25.143399+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-06-28T23:27:28.238871+00:00 app[web.1]: > boilerplate@1.0.0 start /app
2017-06-28T23:27:28.238856+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-28T23:27:28.481358+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server is up on port 6393
2017-06-28T23:27:28.238872+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-06-28T23:27:28.238873+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-28T23:27:28.889667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-06-28T23:27:51.827338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=4b2d9421-8ba7-4d3d-98ca-f073fe8f6cac fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=40ms status=302 bytes=367 protocol=https
2017-06-28T23:27:51.888303+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=1fe1b607-afda-4fea-b978-e233b91b3afa fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
2017-06-29T00:01:53.127178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-06-29T00:01:53.127811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-06-29T00:01:54.075199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-06-29T00:01:54.328736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-06-29T02:23:40.044207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-06-29T02:23:40.044490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-06-29T02:23:42.268297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-06-29T02:23:44.173968+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-29T02:23:44.173981+00:00 app[web.1]: > boilerplate@1.0.0 start /app
2017-06-29T02:23:44.173982+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-06-29T02:23:44.173983+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-29T02:23:44.363574+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server is up on port 33572
2017-06-29T02:23:44.528325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-06-29T02:23:46.107998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=be07f893-a463-4382-aca3-f54874f9f19f fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
2017-06-29T02:23:46.346724+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=234b0939-c39f-471f-ab49-f74543c9aff5 fwd="74.108.115.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
2017-06-29T02:59:02.062842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-06-29T02:59:02.063293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-06-29T02:59:02.592723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-06-29T02:59:02.703229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-06-29T13:41:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2017-06-29T13:42:16.524993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-06-29T13:42:16.287740+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user 
2017-06-29T13:42:16.287740+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f285b3c0 by user 
2017-06-29T13:41:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-06-29T13:42:19.563322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-06-29T13:42:23.209966+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-29T13:42:23.209986+00:00 app[web.1]: > boilerplate@1.0.0 start /app
2017-06-29T13:42:23.209987+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-06-29T13:42:23.209987+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-29T13:42:23.634312+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server is up on port 44049
2017-06-29T13:42:24.099862+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-06-29T13:43:26.907194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=ab9bfd92-c388-4b0e-a4fb-f27a2099cf24 fwd="24.103.114.219" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=50ms status=302 bytes=367 protocol=https
2017-06-29T13:43:27.054007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-hollows-69063.herokuapp.com request_id=2b112cae-f8d1-40d0-8ba7-092f5a191086 fwd="24.103.114.219" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=110ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=http
```

package. json file:

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple react app ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"

  },
  "author": "redacted",
  "license": "MIT ",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "npm": "^5.0.3",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.0"
  }
}
```

server. js file:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(function (req, res, next){
 if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'http') {
   next();
 } else {
      res.redirect('http://' + req.hostname + req.url);
 }
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Express server is up on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Could you explain to me why do I get errors and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you add dependencies in your package.json.
Also you can try change the version of node, that is used on your heroku server, by adding this parameter to your package.json. For example:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.0.0"
  },
```

Also you should use port determined by Heroku in your enviroment

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
//...
app.listen(app.get('port'), function (err) {
//...
})
```

Comment: thanks for the response, playing around with node and npm versions didnt fix the problem for me, i posted the package.json and server.js file in case they might help in troubleshooting, thanks again.